# Saving subclasses in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following class structure.

```
class User{
    String name;
    Thing things[];
}

interface Thing{

}

class ThingA implements Thing{
    String something;
}

class ThingB implements Thing{
    String anotherthing;
}
```

What is the best way to save `User` objects in firebase?

What I'm currently do is like;

```
{
    "users": {
        "name": "My Name",
        "thingAs": [{
            "something": "value",
        }],
        "thingBs": [{
            "anotherthing": "value",
        }]
    }
}
```

I can't think of another way of doing this. Do you have any better solutions?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that you need a marker in the database that indicates the type of each thing. In your data model you've modeled that marker as the key of a node under which you store the things of that type.

An alternative model would be to store the type marker for each item separately. So:

```
"userA": {
    "name": "My Name",
    "things": [{
        "type": "ThingA",
        "something": "value",
    }, {
        "type": "ThingB",
        "anotherthing": "value",
    }]
}
```

Both models can work, and both models have advantages and disadvantages. A few of these that I can quickly think of:

- Your model saves the type marker only once, while the alternative model I propose saves it for each item.
- My alternative model can maintain the order of the items, regardless of their type, while your model can only maintain the order within the same type.

There is no singular correct model here. As usual with NoSQL data modeling it all depends on the use-cases of your app. For example: if the order of the items is not important to your app, then the model in your question can save you some database storage space.